# UML state diagrams and Moore/Mealy machines

Tags: uml, state, diagram, fsm

How to model Moore and Mealy machines with UML state diagrams? Besides, how to represent outputs in those diagrams? Through Actions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UML state diagrams have the characteristics of both Mealy and Moore state machines.

To represent a pure Mealy machine, you use only actions on transitions:

```
stateA -- TRIGGER [guard] / action() --> stateB
```

To represent a pure Moore machine, you use only entry or exit actions to states, but you don't use actions on transitions:

```
stateA
   entry/ actionA();

stateB
   entry/ actionB();
```

When you use both actions on transitions and entry/exit actions in states, you have a mix of Mealy and Moore machines.

Answer (score 0):

A statemachine can define behavior (p. 309 of the latest UML 2.5.1 specs):

> **14.2.3.4.3 State entry, exit, and doActivity Behaviors**
>
> A State may have an associated entry Behavior. This Behavior, if defined, is executed whenever the State is entered through an **external** Transition. In addition, a State may also have an associated exit Behavior, which, if defined, is executed whenever the State is exited.
>
> A State may also have an associated doActivity Behavior. This Behavior commences execution when the State is entered (but only after the State entry Behavior has completed) and executes concurrently with any other Behaviors that may be associated with the State, until:
>
> - it completes (in which case a completion event is generated) or
> - the State is exited, in which case execution of the doActivity Behavior is aborted.
>
> The execution of a doActivity Behavior of a State is not affected by the firing of an internal Transition of that State.

Read on at p. 320 about the notation of the latter.